# how to save the array in mongodb by using node.js

Tags: node.js

```
{
    "_id" :
    "statinaryId":"01",
    "booktype":[
            {
                "BookId":"01",
                "smallBook": "book1",
                "plainBook": "book1",
                "ruledBook": "book1",
                "longBook": "book1"
            }
         ]
                 
    "pens": [
        {
            "Penid": "01",
            "gelpen": "pen1",
            "griperpen": "pen1",
            "colorpen":"pen1"
        }
    ]
   "pencils": [
         {
            "pencilid": "01",
            "penpencil": "penpencil1",
            "colorpencil":"pencil1"

          }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a MongoDB record, you can save/store data in any format (Array, Nested Objects...), if it's a valid JSON.

However if you are using Mongoose & created a schema then you need to define the document format / schema. Else those fields will be discarded while saving the record.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be something like this:

Assuming your mongo project name as `mongoProject` and `schema as BookSchema`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
//make a connection        

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongoProject');

//get reference to database
var db = mongoose.connection;
 
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
 
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("Connection Successful!");
    
    // define Schema
    var BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      price: Number,
      quantity: Number
    });
 
    // compile schema to model
    var Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema, 'bookstore');
 
    // documents array
    var books = [{ name: 'Mongoose Tutorial', price: 10, quantity: 25 },
                    { name: 'NodeJS tutorial', price: 15, quantity: 5 },
                    { name: 'MongoDB Tutorial', price: 20, quantity: 2 }];
 
    // save multiple documents to the collection referenced by Book Model
    Book.collection.insert(books, function (err, docs) {
      if (err){ 
          return console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection");
      }
    });
    
});
```

When run using node program

[image: running node program]

Hope this works for you!!!